Returning multiple rows of output based on a condition
I have the following table with id:



id




1


1


3


2


2


3


2


3


4



I am trying to find the number or numbers that occur most frequently
I have written the query which groups the ids by their count:
select  id, count(*) as num 
from id
group by id
order by num desc

This query returns



id
count(*)




2
3


3
3


1
2


4
1



I need those rows for which the count(*) is maximum, I need the output to be



id
count(*)




2
3


3
3



How do I return only those rows for which the num is max?

Please clarify your expected output. 2 roes have num  = 3.
